# Flutter website on firebase hosting works fine with domain 1 but not domain 2

Tags: firebase-hosting, flutter-web

I am using flutter web to create a website for my buisness. I am hosting it on firebase hosting with the url
https://xspectre-9a3b3.web.app/ 
Now when I added the new domain
https://xspectre.net
The website does not load in this domain and gives the error

```
main.dart.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
(index):1 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('https://xspectre.net/') with script ('https://xspectre.net/flutter_service_worker.js'): The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html').
```

It does not work with https://xspectre-9a3b3.firebaseapp.com/ either. What should I do?

**EDIT**

I discovered the real error is not the MIME type one since it is in my real project too. The actual error is somehow

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
```

When I open the main.dart.js it shows me different code then it should. It shows me the html files not the main.dart.js code and I think that is what is causing the problem. I dont know how or why the files are different for both the URLs.

**EDIT 2 **

Finally figured out the root problem.
Whenever I try to do firebase init, it goes to initialize the whole flutter directory. This means that it says,

```
You're about to initialize a Firebase project in this directory:

  C:\FlutterProjects\xspectre
```

and not

```
You're about to initialize a Firebase project in this directory:

  C:\FlutterProjects\xspectre\build
```

Now I need to figure out how to do firebase init and deloy in the /build and not root

Comment: `main.dart.js` does not exist and the default `index.html` content are being returned instead. Make sure you are building and deploying all the assets and loading them from the correct path.

Comment: If the problem was with the code, it would not have loaded in url1 and url2

Comment: The website at https://xspectre-9a3b3.web.app doesn't load correctly either.

It seems you have a bad deployment (main.dart.js and flutter_service_worker.js are missing) or your firebase hosting is not configured correctly.

What is the content of your firebase.json file?

Comment: Wait I just figured out the real problem. Whenever I try to do firebase init, it goes to initialize the whole flutter directory (better explained in the question). Now I need to figure out how to do firebase init in the /build and not root

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The website probably still works for you as it is already cached by the service worker. Try with another browser and it will not work.

`firebase init` should be run in the project directory, not in the build directory.

After that, edit your firebase.json file to look like

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build/web",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ],
    "headers": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Cache-Control",
            "value": "no-cache"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

`"public": "build/web"` points to the directory where the files for deployment are.

Now you can do `flutter build web` and `firebase deploy`

Comment: My firebase.json was alright, just in wrong location. But your comment helped me crack the problem. I just shifted its location manually. Thanks a lot

Comment: After cracking my head for 30 minutes. I found this. Thank you.