# Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'main.dart.js:1 in firebase web

Tags: firebase, flutter-web

When I run flutter build web, the web app works fine but when I use firebase, I get this error.

This is my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <!--
    If you are serving your web app in a path other than the root, change the
    href value below to reflect the base path you are serving from.

    The path provided below has to start and end with a slash "/" in order for
    it to work correctly.

    Fore more details:
    * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base
  -->
  <base href="/">

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <meta name="description" content="A new Flutter project.">

  <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="************">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">

  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>

  <title>engineering_project</title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
</head>
<body>
<!-- This script installs service_worker.js to provide PWA functionality to
     application. For more information, see:
     https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers -->
<script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      window.addEventListener('flutter-first-frame', function () {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('flutter_service_worker.js');
      });
    }
    </script>
<script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
<!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->

<!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
     https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.3/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.5.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
<script>
  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "*****************************",
    authDomain: "****************************",
    databaseURL: "*******************************",
    projectId: "***************",
    storageBucket: "*******************",
    messagingSenderId: "****************",
    appId: "*****************************",
    measurementId: "***************"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

This is my flutter doctor -v:

> [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.867], locale en-US)
> • Flutter version 2.0.0 at C:\Dave\folder\Flutter\flutter
> • Framework revision 60bd88df91 (3 weeks ago), 2021-03-03 09:13:17 -0800
> • Engine revision 40441def69
> • Dart version 2.12.0

> [✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
> • Android SDK at C:\Users\davet.DESKTOP-H071RK1\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
> • Platform android-30, build-tools 29.0.2
> • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
> • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
> • All Android licenses accepted.

> [✓] Chrome - develop for the web
> • Chrome at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

> [✓] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2019 16.8.6)
> • Visual Studio at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community
> • Visual Studio Community 2019 version 16.8.31019.35
> • Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.18362.0

> [✓] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
> • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
> • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
>  https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
> • Dart plugin can be installed from:
>  https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
> • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

> [✓] VS Code (version 1.54.1)
> • VS Code at C:\Users\davet.DESKTOP-H071RK1\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
> • Flutter extension version 3.20.0

> [✓] Connected device (3 available)
> • Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.867]
> • Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 89.0.4389.90
> • Edge (web)        • edge    • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 89.0.774.57

> • No issues found!

Comment: did you initialize firebase?

Comment: @codesPliff I did

Comment: Those look like they are old versions. 
Can you try to update them? Have a look here (https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#expandable-8)

For instance:
<!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.3.1/firebase-app.js"></script>

<!-- Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
     https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.3.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>

Comment: I was having the same issue and found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65991926/6851358)